# How to minimise boolean algebra ~(a+~b)(a~b+c)(b+~c)

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I don't know exactly what should I do after using DeMorgans law. No matter what I do I can't get the simplest form which is ~abc

```
~(a+~b)(a~b+c)(b+~c) = ~ab(a~b+c)(b+~c)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [K-map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to minimize it using pen and paper?

Comment: So what is your question exactly?  Are you just looking for someone to do this homework problem for you, or a tutorial on Boolean algebra, or what? Ask a more specific question!

Comment: You can use (twice) that conjuction distributes over disjunction

Comment: I don't know what should I do after using DeMorgans law. Is there some patern that I should follow. Any tutorial that isn't K-map. Maybe some software to help me minimise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see why this is true?

```
(a~b+c)(b+~c)
= a~bb + a~b~c + cb + c~c
```

?

First ensure that you *thoroughly* understand why that is true.

Now, what do you know about `a~bb` and `c~c`?

Can you complete the proof from here?

Comment: I've got it, thanks! I just had to remember few parts.